# Replacing { with "", in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
{ TestAddCardForMerchant }
```

I wish to replace `{`,`}` with `""`. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [`String.replaceAll()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and the `"[{}]"` regular expression:

```
String replaced = "{ TestAddCardForMerchant }".replaceAll("[{}]","\"");
```

The String `replaced` will be `" TestAddCardForMerchant "`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to replace `{}` only with pair.

```
String result = str.replaceAll("\\{([^}]+)\\}", "\"$1\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
myString.replaceAll("[{}]", "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to replace all ocurrences of `{}` from your string..
`[]` in `[{}]` is used to denote character class.. It means `{` or `}`..

Also, you need to escape `"` with a backslash, as it has special meaning in Java..
So, here's is your regex, to achieve what you need :-

```
"{test}".replaceAll("[{}]", "\"")
```